# How to load resources from classpath in itext7?

Tags: itext, itext7, html2pdf

How to load resources like images, css and fonts from the classpath with iText 7?

Formerly I used the `ITextRenderer` to do so:

```
ITextRenderer renderer = createITextRenderer();
renderer.setDocumentFromString(htmlContent, "classpath:/templates/");
```

I tried it with the `ConverterProperties`, but that does not do the job.

```
ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties().setBaseUri("classpath:/templates/");
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(htmlContent, outputStream, properties);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within Spring Boot Applications the classpath protocoll handler can be registered by using the `TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory`. The baseURI can be set as stated in the question.

```
org.apache.catalina.webresources.TomcatURLStreamHandlerFactory.register();
ConverterProperties properties = new ConverterProperties().setBaseUri("classpath:/templates/");
```